# How to search against product options

Tags: catalogsearch, search, custom-options, option

I have products which have options that include their associated part#'s and model#'s in text as shown here http://greengaskets.com/index.php/manufacturer/bally-gasket-profile-10130.html

However I am unable produce results when searching text published in product options. How can I include product options in the search function?

Comment: You can't, we use an extension for this otherwise you need to add all the values to an attribute as already suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Product attributes can be included in search results as long as you put `Use in Advanced Search` and `Use in Quick Search` to `yes`.

Custom product options however are not used in search. I would advice to put the values in an Attribute. Changing Magento search functionality to include custom options might be a big challenge.